# Clear table settings from previous engine

Tags: mysql, myisam, mariadb

I running MariaDB and on myisam tables try change engine to aria. After changing it back, I have some errors with tables. I need to set rowformat=fixed, phpadmin says ok but format is still dynamic :-/ in console I get warning:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> ALTER TABLE test.mytable ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

Table storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support the create option 'TRANSACTIONAL=0'
```

transactional=0 is parameter from aria engine which stay on table after change engine to myisam, but how to delete this?

if I make copy of table, settings is copied too...and re-create tables manually is not possible, this problem affect large amount of tables :(